# Retrieve an array property of a document, count the length of array and store in a variable before outputting in json

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

may i know how can i retrieve an array property of a document, count the length of array and store in a variable before outputting in json?

```
db.collection('document', function(err, collection){
    var a = 0;
    var doc = [];
    collection.find().sort({date: -1}).each(function(err, docs){    
        if(docs ==  null){
            db.close();
        }
        else{
            doc.push(docs.property.length);
        }
    });
    res.json({d : doc});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
var doc = [];
db.collection('document').find({}).sort({"date": -1}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
  if (err) throw err;

  docs.forEach(function (document) {
    doc.push(document.property.length);
  });
});
res.json({d: doc});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done on both application layer and db layer (using aggregation). This is how it can be done using aggregation. I'm not sure about nodeJs layer.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $project : {
         title : "$title",
         description : "$description"
         arraySize : {$size : "$arrayField"}
      }
   }
])
```